# Authentication with a Java EE application server from an Android app

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, http-authentication

I'm trying to develop an `android` app which needs to fetch information from a servlet hosted in my Java EE application server.

To access this servlet, I need to be first authenticated with the Application server. I searched the web to get information on how exactly this works. During authentication how dows the `android` app store the cookie, and then how does it transfers the cookie to the server for every request?

I got some bits and pieces of information about `HttpClient`. I'm not sure if this is the correct one which I should be using. It will be a great help if someone could guide me. If there are any documents available please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is native app, if so, first you need to authenticate and get the cookie. It would be your responsibility to store the cookie some where and pass it in sussequent http calls. If it is not native, I am not sure how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) documentation page is what you are looking for?